# QGIS how to change raster resolution

Tags: qgis, raster, resolution

I'm currently working on comparing raster maps between years to detect landscape change between them. One issue is that at one point the resolution changed from 25x25 meters to 5x5 meters. I'm sure I've done it before, but can't remember how, but is there a way to change the 5x5 resolution raster to a 25x25 resolution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing resolution of a raster is called resampling. It can be done in qgis using the `r.resample` tool. You can specify the cell size.

[image]

Comment: Hi I was about to comment to myself that I remembered how to do the trick. I ended up using raster>projections>warp (reproject). Which seems to have done the trick as well!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Padmanabha's comment, I ended up using **raster**>**projections**>**warp (reproject)**.

This did the trick as well! It also seems to work better for very large files.